# Selenium, how to get last element of a class in c#

Tags: c#, css, selenium

I am trying to return the last element with the class name MyClass. I am using selenium, but the following code does not work. I am not sure if I am setting it up correctly.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
Console.WriteLine((string)js.ExecuteScript(".MyClass:last-child"));
```

Comment: This is a css question more than anything. Without seeing the structure of the DOM it's not simple to say what the issue is.

Comment: No need to know dom structure. Just want a general idea on how to get last item with a class name without having to grab all elements then reverse the list .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using C# as the tag in your question indicates, you don't need JSE. One way to do this is to use LINQ

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;

ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".MyClass"));
IWebElement lastElement = elements.ElementAt(elements.Count - 1);
string lastElementText = lastElement.Text;
```

---

Just for fun try...

```
string lastElementText = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".MyClass:last-child")).Text;
```

NOTE: Turns out this doesn't work... it returns the text of the first element. I'm assuming that `:last-child` is not supported.

---

From a further discussion, OP wanted to get the text of the last element and then know when it changes (within a few seconds). This code should take care of that case...

```
By locator = By.CssSelector(".MyClass");
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(locator);
IWebElement lastElement = elements.ElementAt(elements.Count - 1);

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(locator).Text != lastElement.Text);
```

Comment: @Juansdk Make sure your locator is correct and that there are elements that match it that exist on the page. You may need to add a wait.

Comment: Just added it, getting a element id. Any way to actually print the content of the element? Also, is there another way to get hte last element without getting all of the elemnts and wasting resources?

Comment: If you want the text of the element, you can use `string lastElementText = lastElement.Text;` It's not really that big of a deal. If you were locating 1k elements on the page, I might start to worry. I updated the answer and added the code to get the text as you requested.

Comment: One of the cleanest pieces of code on this forum. Thank you very much!! I am actually pulling around 50 elements. Would this be ok?

Comment: You are welcome. I think you should be just fine. Run it and see how it goes... my guess is that it will be < 1s to get these elements.

Comment: Did you ever try `driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".MyClass:last-child"));`? I assumed that since you tried it and it didn't work it wouldn't work but it's working in the browser when I just tried it. I updated my answer at the bottom. Try that code and see if it works for you.

Comment: I actually did try, but did not include the double semi colon. Let me try this!

Comment: Sorry... that was a typo in my comment. It should be as I have in the answer, ".MyClass:last-child". In your question you are using JSE and I wondered if that was causing an issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229075/discussion-between-juansdk-and-jeffc).